# How to search in a jquery array to see if any items in the array exist in any part of the text in a div?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm really close to having this working. I need to see if part of the string of text inside div containers of a certain class contain one of the items inside an array.

Here is what I tried in order to try to use `indexof` to try to search the string instead of `inArray` **(this code doesn't work)**:

```
var arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$('.mydiv').each(function() {
    if(arr.indexOf(($(this).text())!==-1 ) {
        // do something like functions, increments, and other things
    }
};
```

Here is an example html. In this example, the expected result is that three of these divs should result in it being found in the array. You can see `item1` for example in the second div, but for this div the query code in `// do something` should be run. *(Note that there are some other characters in the string like colons and slashes.)*

```
<div class="mydiv">3.c:e/e.x 1w</div>
<div class="mydiv">0/item1:e</div>
<div class="mydiv">c3/i:e.ra7 item3</div>
<div class="mydiv">9.m:c/e1x</div>
<div class="mydiv">item2:2/w</div>
```

---

I tried the `inArray` code but I discovered that it only worked on an EXACT match.

For example, the below code **does not work** because in the example html below, only the first div which is an exact match works, but not the second div. The required result is that **both** the divs in the example below containing `item1` should both work, but of course the third div which doesn't contain anything in the array should not work as items in the array are not found in the text.

```
$('.mydiv').each(function() {
    if($.inArray($(this).text(),arr)!==-1 ) {
        // do something
    }
};

<div class="mydiv">item1</div>
<div class="mydiv">miw0/item1w:e/doi</div>
<div class="mydiv">something else</div>
```

How can I get this to work so that if any of the array items are found in any part of the text inside the div, then the code will work and it will `// do something`?

Please use the lease code and also please do not use a `for` loop because I need to use functions inside the code.

Comment: I don't understand what your thing is with  `for` loops. Surely they can be embedded in functions, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to loop through array to comapare with each value. below line will check exact match in array.

```
if($.inArray($(this).text(),arr)!==-1 )
```

but you are looking for part of string. so you need to use **indexOf** function.

```js
var arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
var _div=$('.mydiv');
_div.each(function() {
          var divText=$(this).text()
          for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
          {
               var arrayElement=arr[i];
               if(divText.indexOf(arrayElement) > -1 ) {
                 console.log($(this).text());
            }
         }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">item1</div>
<div class="mydiv">miw0/item1w:e/doi</div>
<div class="mydiv">something else</div>
```

Comment: Can you please remove the `for` loop? I also need to use functions and increments inside the code. I think there should be a simplified solution, this seems overly complex.

Comment: Update: it does work by the way. I removed the unnecessary `_div` var but your code does work. I do wonder if it can be simplified but I am satisfied it works and I did include functions and increments. For my increments I had to change my increment `i` to a `j` so it didn't conflict with your `i` in the `for` loop.